# Java Spring Hibernate application runs on local, but not in aws's ecs docker

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, tomcat, docker

Dear Java & Docker Masters,

Have you encounter issue that pulls out your hair?  Try this:

I have a Java Spring Hibernate web application that able to run successfully on my local that build via Gradle. IT is compile using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_101.  It runs under Tomcat 7.0.72 (and tomcat runs Open on JDK 1.8.0_102).  It runs the war perfectly well.  Why do I have such different jdk version? because i want to mimic the dev server below.

My Dev server is a docker under aws ecs, with only one container image. And this container image uses the tomcat:7.0.72-jre8 image base.  The same war application that is running inside the container throws the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'agencyRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.mnetmobile.data.entities.Agency

I drag that war file, and runs on my local, and it works like a champ. All JDK versions are the same, tomcat version are the same. the only thing different, is a windows 7 laptop, vs an ubuntu linux and runs docker. (All the path different is N/A because there are all relative path)

Any idea which hole i might have missed?

Comment: Do you run your war localy and on aws with the same spring profile or using different profiles?

Comment: Also, are there any differences in Tomcat configuration - different jar files in the Tomcat lib folder, differences in server.xml or context.xml files?

Comment: IT is a standard Tomcat, and i didnt touch the lib folder yet. and i just check the two folders, yes, they are the same library.

Comment: @Issam when you say spring profile, can i assume it is the spring configuration? i using Spring 3, and annotation all the way, no XML.

Comment: @David Miller, you were right! there was a configuration different that i missed even after using Beyond Compare.  I'll accept your answer if you post one.

Comment: Thanks!  I posted an answer.  What was the different configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow there must be some difference in the configuration of the two Tomcat servers.  Since the Java version, the Tomcat version, and the war file are all the same; there must be some difference in the Tomcat configuration, either in the Tomcat lib folder, or the context.xml or server.xml or someplace.

Comment: True enough, my application.properties file has a path. the differences were only 2 characters and my eye's selective vision has failed me this time.    Thanks David!